# Strange php error with a variable name

Tags: php

This is a big puzzle for me.

I have a line of code like this:

```
$Fields = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
```

I then call it like this:

```
<?php echo $Fields['BusinessName']; ?>
```

The strange thing is that there are no errors but no data is shown. But when I rename the variable **$Fields** as **$Field**, the data shows.

For local testing I used Ubuntu and the error was first noticed on the host (LAMP).

I checked to see if $Fields is a reserved word in PHP but I can't seem to find any hints on this.

Appreciate any inputs on this.
Thanks!

Here's the code that WORKS:

```
$strQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblAds WHERE AdRef = '{$ThisAd}' LIMIT 1 ";
$Result = mysql_query($strQuery);
$Field = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
```

Now in the html body area, I insert the echo statement like mentioned earlier in the post and it works.

But the moment I change it to $Fields, there's no error, and no output. When I say no output, the field contents is shown as blank. But the page continues to load without the data.

*Just for the ones curious, there is one error alert about a session variable already being declared but this is not relevant.*

I hope this is clear.

Comment: You set variable `$Fields` and you wonder why `$Field` is empty? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Uh? You name a variable in a way and call it in another, where's the strange error? :/ And with no error display settings, everything will be a mistery, man!

Comment: Excuse me for the typing error @Juhana. I've corrected the code.

Comment: @DamienPirsy, I'm sorry for the typing error. There's my edited version.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you didn't make the same typo in the actual code?

Comment: @Juhana, I'm positive. That was the problem. **$Field** works but not **$Fields**

Comment: All I can do is to repeat what others have said: show a concise, complete example that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise we just have to assume you modify `$Fields` somewhere between setting and echoing it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no magic in PHP.

if one of variables doesn't work - there is just a silly typo.

**turn `error_erporting(E_ALL);`** as you've been told already, to get help from your PHP in spotting that typo.
that's all

if you'd be still unable to spot it - **at least provide a full, reproduceable code**, to let everyone run it and see what is wrong.

Again.
Look, you have to post **the code**, not it's wordy description.

for the question consists of `"But the moment I change variable name, something went wrong"` the **only** possible answer is "there is some mistake". Don't you understand it? It is **impossible** to give a certain answer for the vague question!

> - Now in the html body area,

WHY in HTML body area? Why not right in place? How many code in between these places? How many possibilities for this varible being *overwritten*?
Why not to just add one line to this code, echoing your variable, *immediately*?

Comment: Thank you @Col. Shranel. I tried that and there were no errors reported.

Comment: go on. post the code. NOT the whole code of the project but relevant part. I am sure it won't exceed 5 lines.

Comment: also make sure you can see errors on screen. PHP can be set up to not to show error messages on the screen but to log them in a file

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$Fields = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
foreach($Fields as $field){
   echo $field['BusinessName'];
}
```

of course you cant echo the array since $Fields is an array. you should foreach it

Comment: The result set is correct in my code. Please see if the code makes sense for not showing the data now. Thanks!

Comment: you mean you save the array to $Fields but it shows nothing?? instead, it can be shown when you echo-ing $field?

try var_dump($Fields) and var_dump($Field). Is it a same?
maybe your variable $Field showing the previous data on it. not your mysql fetch.
check your code, is there something else that used variable $Field.

why dont you just change the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call `var_dump($var)` function to display data contained in your variables `$Fields` or `$Field` or any other.

Also it can be helpful to look for some working examples of using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` on php.net.

Answer (score -1):

You had `$Field` declared and initialized previously.

`$Fields` is a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
$Fields[0]['BusinessName'];
```

It has multiple "BusinessName"s, so the variable actually is filled with a bunch of integer keys, which are then associated with your fields, including "BusinessName".

Comment: Thanks @Nick Liu, it's only one record. Hang on, I'll post some lines of the code.